# How to generate URL in service layer of ASP.NET MVC 3 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, url, web-applications, service-layer

I am looking for a simple way (if it exists) to generate a URL in a service class for a specified controller and action in an ASP.NET MVC 3 web application. I want to do this in the service layer because of needing to encode this URL in a QR code.

This is simple in a View or in a controller because of the UrlHelper available through System.Web.Mvc so I could create the beginning of the URL in the controller action that uses my service class but I was hoping to do it at the point of QR code generation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what code have you tried yourself so far.. can you post what you have tried..?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A major reason for having distinct layers is separation of concerns.  The service layer should not concern itself with request routing.

I would pass the URL into the service layer and have the service layer return the generated QR code.

Comment: Yep, Use the Url helper in the controller, and pass it to the service layer as argument.

Comment: Absolutely exactly precisely what I was thinking.

Comment: I wasn't sure if that was best or not. Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: What if you have to send an email with a link to the application's endpoint, then you would need to construct the link in the service layer!

Answer (score 5):

I understand the separation of concerns but sometimes a developer has to do what a developer has to do!

So here is what I have done:

```cs
var Url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
var myUrl = Url.RouteUrl("routeName", new { controller="ControllerName", action="Index", area="", otherDictionaryEntries="otherId"});
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
private readonly LinkGenerator _urlHelper;
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

public MyUrlService(LinkGenerator urlHelper, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    _urlHelper = urlHelper;
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}

public string MyCreateUrl() 
{ 
    var url = _urlHelper.GetUriByAction("Index1", "Home", new { param1 = "myparam1", param2 = "myparam2" }, _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext!.Request.Scheme, _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host); 
}
```

Url output:

```
"http://localhost:5241/Home/Index1?param1=myparam1&param2=myparam2"
```

We do not forget to add our services via Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```